# Javascript promises and their parameters

Tags: javascript, scope, promise

in the following .then structure, I am having problems returning the image object to the next .then.

At the point where I return image, it is no longer available because it is out of the initial scope.

Is there a correct way to make it available there, or am I off with my coding here?

```
  .then(function(image) {        


    image.data().then(function(result) {
        var base64 = result.toString("base64");
        var largeImage = new Parse.File("l.jpg", { base64: base64 });
        largeImage.save().then(function(result,image) {
            post.set('largeImageUrl',result.url());
            return image;    /// <-- undefined. How can access the image object here?
        });
    });



  }).then(function(image) {
```

Comment: Don't forget that you need to **`return`** the `largeImage.save().then(…)`.

Comment: Change `function(result,image)` to `function(result)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original `image` variable is not out of scope; variables are visible to all functions defined within the same block, even if the functions are defined within other functions. That is, a variable's scope is the function it is defined in. If there are variables of the same name across various functions, the inner-scoped function will have a new reference for that scope and no longer reference the outer function's value.

However, the original `image` variable is shadowed by another variable also called `image` in the innermost scope, the `function(result,image)` you pass to `largeImage.save().then()`. If you still need a reference to the outer `image` variable, you should rename your inner `image` variable to something else.

Since that innermost `image` variable is `undefined`, it looks to be a leftover from a copy+paste, and might not even belong on the parameter list of `function(result,image)` in the first place.

Comment: @sweetamylase Is there a point to your edit? The sentences you've inserted just reiterate what I've already said, making the answer quite repetitive. If you feel it is unclear and might warrant a better explanation, you're welcome to post your own answer.

Comment: Your answer is great. I wanted to expand the explanation of variable scope so the OP has better understanding of how it works. But didn't think it warranted posting my own answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the scope, it works now. Additionally to removing the image parameter, I also had to add 'return' in front of 'image.data()' as well as 'largeImage.save()'